# How to execute several lines into a .txt

Tags: bash, scripting, cat

I am using SSH; In a folder I have the next files:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 german german   48 Apr 29 10:45 prueba.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 german german   23 Apr 29 10:43 script1.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 german german   23 Apr 29 10:45 script2.sh

cat script1.sh
echo "Test 1: $(date)"

cat script2.sh
echo "Test 2: $(date)"

cat prueba.txt
bash /home/german/script1.sh
bash /home/german/script2.sh
```

but when …

```
`cat prueba.txt`
```

only execute the first line “script1.sh”

```
Test 1: Wed Apr 29 10:48:48 COT 2015
```

How can I execute more than one line in a txt file?

Comment: `bash /home/german/prueba.txt`

Comment: @Costas the same result.

Comment: `cat /home/german/prueba.txt | bash`

Comment: @costas sorry, I made a mistake, the two commands work fine, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Costas - good answer!

And since they're sh scripts,

sh /home/german/prueba.txt

will work, as well.

And, BTW, this was supposed to be a comment (isn't that what Add Comment is supposed to do?)